# Extract data from HTML code in PHP variable

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract data from HTML code in a PHP variable.

The HTML is the following:

```
<tr class="tr1">
  <td align="right">
    1.
  </td>
  <td align="left">
     <input type="hidden" name="now[8116632]" value="98" />
     <input type="hidden" name="add[8116632]" value="39" />
     <input type="hidden" name="sec_value[8116632]" value="45720000" />
     <div id="uid8116632"></div>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=8116632" target="_blank"
    onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=8116632',
    c41c569a1b9c46c4cbc4bc58f37cb05f'))">kana</a>
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    98
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    45.720.000
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr2">
  <td align="right">
    2.
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="hidden" name="now[8121292]" value="90" />
    <input type="hidden" name="add[8121292]" value="45" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sec_value[8121292]" value="36500000" />
    <div id="uid8121292"></div>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <a href="playerInfo.phtml?pid=8121292" target="_blank"
    onclick="return(openSmallWindow('playerInfo.phtml?pid=8121292',
    'c41c569a1b9c46c4cbc4bc58f37cb05f'))">Xoán Manuel Pérez Chaves</a>
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    90
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    36.500.000
  </td>
</tr>
```

In this code I want to extract:

```
<td align="right">1.</td>
```

This number as `$position`

```
<input type="hidden" name="now[8116632]" value="98" />
```

The idnumber which is between square bracks in attributte name as $id, the value as $value

```
<input type="hidden" name="sec_value[8121292]" value="36500000" />
```

This value as `$price`

My php code so far is this:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($result2);

$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="tr1"]');
```

Now how can I get the variables I tell you guys before? `$position,$id,$value and $price`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For element text use something like

```
.../td[@align='right']/text()
```

For attribute values use something like

```
.../td[@align='left']/input[1]/@value
```

and for parsing the brackets, you're going to have to use the substring functions, which is going to get messy.  substring-before and substring-after are probably what you're looking for.  Check this out as a reference: [xpath: string manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374219/xpath-string-manipulation)

Comment: Going to check that. Thank you

Comment: "..." represents what the original poster wrote: "//*[@class="tr1"]".

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use more input with hidden type and give them appropriate names like:

```
<tr class="tr1">
<td align="right">1.</td>
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="765434" />
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="89898989" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="100" />
<td>Some description</td>
</tr>
```

It will be much easier to maintain such code and you will have no problem with accessing variables in php.
I'm sorry if this is now you are asking for but for me it's reasonable solution (I may not know all the facts).

If you are not able to change this HTML I recommend you to check SimpleHTMLDom library instead of xpath here are some info:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: I can't modified the HTML code because is extracted from a website with cURL. I need to grab the data from HTML code and store it in the variables i mention early