# XPATH Start parsing after certain characters

Tags: xpath

I want to crawl this URL:

```
<div id="exid" class="page_ex"><a href="/example-g4672949-d999999-r4859506-example-URL.html
```

But only return this value:

"d999999"

How can I make the parse start after the second "-" in this URL, does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: try using a substring function and/or regular expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpath: string manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374219/xpath-string-manipulation)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string using the `substring-before` and `substring-after` methods:

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(//a/@href, '-'), '-'), '-')
```